# Firebase Messaging Notifications not coming through even though database correctly referenced

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I recently started learning about Firebase and its capabilities and I am very impressed about how easy it is to implement. But I run into a very funny issue. I tried to use Firebase functions to send notifications to a specific user when data is written to the real-time database. I combed the whole internet to find a solution and still got nothing. Even the logs in the functions tab aren't showing up. I think I am not seeing something. Please help.

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Hotel_Complaints/Users/{usersId}/')
.onWrite((change,context) =>{

var user_id = context.params.usersId;
console.log(user_id);
// Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();

var device_token = admin.database().ref('/Hotel_Staff/'+user_id+'/device_token').once('value');

return device_token.then(result => {

var token_id = result.val();

console.log(token_id);

var str = eventSnapshot.issue_description;

var payload = {
    notification: {
        title: eventSnapshot.staff_name,
        body: str,

    }   

};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(function (response) {
        // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
        // contents of response.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });

});

});
```

**FirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String info_body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String info_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String click_action = "Home";

        showNotification(info_body, info_title, click_action);



}

private void showNotification(String info_body, String info_title, String click_action) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (click_action) {
        case "Home":
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            break;
        default:
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            break;

    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int notificationId = 1;
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";
    String GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.softwaremongul.reporttrackingsystem";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId, channelName, importance);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentTitle(info_title)
            .setContentText(info_body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(info_body));

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());


}

}
```

**And finally the database**
[SNAPSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRoeg.png)

[Functions Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMeNC.png)

Comment: Android code look fine... did you try to send notification from Firebase messaging console?

Comment: Yeah. It worked. And oh, the logs just came in. I have edited the question for you to see it. It says the notification.title should be a string but it is a string.

Comment: If nothing is logged in your Cloud Functions console, the problem is not in the Android code you shared, nor in the body of the Node.js function. The problem is in that case more likely in how you try to trigger the Cloud Function. Please try to reproduce the problem in isolation: just trying to trigger a Cloud Function with just a `console.log` statement or something similar through a database write. Having a simpler, isolated problem will make it much easier to help. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen the logs came through alright but now it is saying notification.title should be a string. But the data is all of strings. What do I do?

Comment: You can see it in the image I added to the question. And please thanks for your help.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMeNC.png

Comment: If the FCM server says that `notification.title` is not a string, I tend to trust it. Keep in mind: it can either be another type, or it might simply not have a value at all (meaning it'd be `undefined`, which is not a string). As said above: it's easiest to help if you spend the time to isolate the problem. At this point it's clear that the problem is not in the Android code. Try reproducing the problem in a small local Node.js script. If you pass a hardcoded string `title: "CodeX",`, it will work. If you pass another type of `undefined` it won't.

Comment: Okay Sir. So I read somewhere on SO that the issue could be from wrong database node referencing. Could that be why I am not getting the notifications?